# How can I properly add Windows 10 start menu shortcuts in WiX?

Tags: pdf, wix, windows-10, shortcut

I have a WiX installer which creates start menu shortcuts for the application and pdf documentation (and another with html documentation). However, I have noticed that Windows 10 does not find the pdf when I search for it in the start menu (it only finds the application). The shortcut is there and if I drill down into the start menu, I will find it - just can't search for it.

I don't think Windows 10 will find shortcuts to anything other than .exe, .bat and .chm. I can create a .bat file that will launch the pdf / html documents but this doesn't seem like the cleanest solution to me.

Does anyone have any other suggestions or opinions?

Comment: This appears to be intentional behavior on Microsoft's part (I'd love to find a documentation link). If possible, I suggest embracing the change. And be thankful your program name doesn't start with 'install'.

Comment: Shortcuts to CHM files are not found either. This behavior was started with Windows 8 and it looks more like a bug than a feature.